# toastr is not working with angular 8 it,s give me error

Tags: angular, roaster

i am using angular 8 toastr but i got this error in console

```
ngx-toastr.js:264 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at ngx-toastr.js:264
at Module../node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5/ngx-toastr.js (ngx-toastr.js:271)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object.0 (main.ts:13)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
(anonymous) @ ngx-toastr.js:264
./node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5/ngx-toastr.js @ ngx-toastr.js:271
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
```

./src/app/app.module.ts @ app.component.ts:8
   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:78
   ./src/main.ts @ main.ts:1
   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:78
   0 @ main.ts:13
   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:78
   checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
   webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
  (anonymous) @ main.js:1
  client:148 [WDS] Warnings while compiling.

i have run these in command line

```
 npm install ngx-toastr --save
 npm install @angular/animations --save
```

in my app.module.ts i have included these line

```
  import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
  import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';

   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     AppRoutingModule,
     BrowserAnimationsModule,
     ToastrModule.forRoot()
    ],
```

i have include this in angular.json

```
 "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
```

this is my component.ts file

```
   import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
   constract(public toastr: ToastrService){}
   ngOnInit() {
  this.toastr.success('hello world', 'Success!');
  }
```

and when i rung angular server using ng serve command it show me this error

```
  WARNING in ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/fesm5/ngx-toastr.js 368:198-206
  "export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in '@angular/core'
```

Comment: It's seems like your are missing some bootstrap version. Check this 
[stackblitz]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vb2gpb

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you have done a simple copy/past from your code but the following line is wrong :

```
 constract(public toastr: ToastrService){}
```

Replace with

```
 constructor(public toastr: ToastrService){}
```

But I'm not sure it could solve your issue because if it did your code wouldn't even be compiling like this.

Maybe you could try npm cache clean --force and npm install to download the dependencies

Comment: Yes I noticed that. He should inject the service through constructor.

Answer (score 0):

the reason that i have got error in console is that the roastr version my angular cli version is 7 and i have use roastr version 11 so this is the reason version is depend on angular cli when i install roastr@7.1.0 so everything working fine and perfect.